# How do i make an if statement if my answer includes something

Tags: python

i am a fairly average coder and i would love to know that if my player says something rand but it includes keywords it would still do a if statement?

For example. Answer = input("Take lantern or leave")
             if answer ==(Includes like "Pickup" instead of take i want this to still run or if they say pickup the lantern etc.

I hope you can help me, if any additional info needed just ask

print ("You can barley see anything around you but can hear loud noises coming from within the cave")
          print ("")
          answer = input (" There is a blue door onfront of you, beside you, beside you is a lantern of which is rusty but working ")

```
 if answer == "take lantern" or answer == "Take lantern":
```

I want it so they don't have to precisely put "Take lantern or something like that, i want keywords like "Pickup" or "Take"

Comment: I would suggest having a list of acceptable words then use `if answer in acceptedwordslist`

Comment: if OP does, then i will ;) but tuxtimo beat me to it anyways

Comment: OP? may i ask what OP is?

Comment: OP stands for "original poster"

Comment: Okay, well my question has been answered now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either check if your `answer` is in a list of expected answers:

```
answer = input("...")
if answer in ["take", "pickup"]:
    ...
```

Or you could check your `answer` with Regular Expressions:

```
import re
...

if re.search("(take|pickup)", answer):
    ....
```

Comment: Do i have to import anything?

Comment: Yes, the `re` module, but just for the second example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html